# Jquery Datepicker, Set Select2 value to null upon selection of date, and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-select2

in Laravel framework I am using Jquery version v3.3.1 and bootstrap-datepicker.js and Select2 4.0.4

and i am making a process on which when

- field change on datepicker which upon change will trigger select2 value to null
- field change on select2 value will trigger change on datepicker field to null

below is my html codes

```
<form class="p-t-10" id="form-search" role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="{{ route('application.record.document_verification.loglist') }}" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group-attached">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group">
                    <div class="form-input-group">
                        <label>
                            <span id="start_date_span">{{ __('Tarikh') }}</span>
                        </label>
                        <input id="start_date" class="form-control" name="start_date">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-custom form-group-default-select2">
                    <label id="label_year_filter"><span>{{ __('Tahun Rekod Dibuat') }}</span></label>
                    <select id="year_filter" name="year_filter" class="full-width autoscroll" data-init-plugin="select2">
                        <option value="" selected="" >{{ __('Pilih satu') }}..</option>
                        <?php for ($i=date('Y');$i>=2018;$i--): ?>
                            <option value={{ $i }}>{{ $i }}</option>
                        <?php endfor ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-custom form-group-default-select2">
                    <label id="label_month_filter"><span>{{ __('Bulan Rekod Dibuat') }}</span></label>
                    <select id="month_filter" name="month_filter" class="full-width autoscroll" data-init-plugin="select2">
                        <option value="" selected="" >{{ __('Pilih satu') }}..</option>
                        <option value=1>{{ __('Januari') }}</option>
                        <option value=2>{{ __('Februari') }}</option>
                        <option value=3>{{ __('Mac') }}</option>
                        <option value=4>{{ __('April') }}</option>
                        <option value=5>{{ __('Mei') }}</option>
                        <option value=6>{{ __('Jun') }}</option>
                        <option value=7>{{ __('Julai') }}</option>
                        <option value=8>{{ __('Ogos') }}</option>
                        <option value=9>{{ __('September') }}</option>
                        <option value=10>{{ __('Oktober') }}</option>
                        <option value=11>{{ __('November') }}</option>
                        <option value=12>{{ __('Disember') }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-right p-t-10 p-b-10">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="resetFilterForm()">Reset</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"></i> {{__('Carian') }}</button>
        </div>
        <button href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default m-t-5" onclick="export_excel_list()"><i class="fa fa-download text-success"></i> EXCEL </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

below is jquery code that i am writing to trigger datepicker on change normally

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({
    language: 'ms',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight:'TRUE',
    endDate: "today",
    onClose: function() {
        $(this).valid();
    },
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    $(this).trigger('change');
});
```

below is jquery i am writing to make sure the code set the select2 value to empty value upon changing datepicker value

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({
    language: 'ms',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight:'TRUE',
    endDate: "today",
    onClose: function() {
        $(this).valid();
    },
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    $(this).trigger('change');

    $('select#year_filter').select2().val("").trigger("change");
});
```

The code above is working correctly without any problems, but now i want to proceed on

- field change on select2 value will trigger change on datepicker field to null

so i write the code as below

```
$('body').on('change',"select#year_filter","select#month_filter",function(){
    $("input[name=start_date]").val("");
})
```

and now its not working correctly , a new bugs occured in which when selection on datepicker is made the datepicker value stays null,  the select2 value change to empty but the datepicker value becomes null

i am not sure what happens, I have check if there is any duplicated name or id but there is none

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Where's your markup? Is there an element with the name "start date"?

Comment: yes there is an element with the name start_date

Comment: You answered my second question but not the first one. No one will be able to help you debug this without seeing your markup.

Comment: i  have edited the question containing the html code